# watching object created on an inherited scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive, watch

I'm trying to create a directive that watches for a file being dragged onto an element.
My issue is that I can't seem to trigger the watch on scope.files
I've also tried creating an isolated scope:

```
scope:{files:'='}
```

and then doing

```
scope.$watch('files',function(){})
```

inside the link function, but no luck.

How do I get this watch to pick up on the files being updated?

I have added "scope.files = []" because it was null initially when watch was being set up.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('dragDrop', [function () {
return {

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.files = [];
        scope.$watch(scope.files, function () {
            if (scope.files !== undefined && scope.files.length === 1) alert("a file has been dropped");
        });
        element.on('dragenter', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css('border', '2px solid #0B85A1');
        });
        element.on('dragover', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        element.on('drop', function (e) {

            $(this).css('border', '0px');
            e.preventDefault();
            //var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
            scope.files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set third parameter of `$watch()` as `true`,

```
scope.$watch('files',function(){},true)
```

here is a nice article about [$watch() vs. $watchCollection()](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-Scope-watch-vs-watchCollection-In-AngularJS.htm)

**UPDATE**

you cannot trigger watch there because you are using primitive object there here is usage of complex object within directive...

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ze7iB2FiV5OTnlw1I7SH?p=preview)

Comment: Hmm, yes I see that this was something I was missing but unfortunately this hasn't resulted in the watch being triggered.

Comment: @MichaelBlom because your files variable is a primitive if you change it to  an complex object child scope do not shadow current item but create new instance if you use primitive object in child scope... check my answer update I add an example...

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help @wickY26, your plunker got me there in the end.